# Can static methods be intercepted with Castle DynamicProxy?

Tags: castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

Can static methods be intercepted with Castle DynamicProxy?

And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Castle DynamicProxy can only proxy types and members that you could have written proxies for by hand, it uses runtime code generation and must comply with the constraints of the CLR.

The DynamicProxy documentation describes the [two general forms of proxy objects it supports](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-kinds-of-proxy-objects.md), inheritance and composition-based.